# NTFS file access time with and without FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

Tags: c, windows, time, ntfs

I am trying to benchmark file read times (sequential access) for NTFS. My code gets a start time, performs a read of size equal to 4096 bytes (cluster size of NTFS on the system) and records the end time. The difference between the two times is then stored and the process is repeated until end of file is reached. The file size I currently use is 40K, so I get 10 time difference values.

When accessing the file opened (using `CreateFile`) without `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, access time for the first block is close to 30 micro-seconds and drops to about 7 micro-seconds for subsequent accesses (due to caching).

When using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, the first block's access time is close to 21 milli-seconds and drops to about 175 micro-seconds for subsequent accesses.

Shouldn't the first block access time be same with or without the flag, since it's not buffered? Also, why do access times drop after the first when the flag is used? I was expecting them to remain constant since we've specified we don't want buffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amongst other things,  the access time include several other (longish) factors beside the actual data transfer time.

Such times include searching the directory structure (the first time only) to find the actual file (this include a 'head seek' time (which is very long as it requires the physical movement of the heads),

then the rotation time to get over the correct sector on the disk,

then the actual data transfer time.

This is followed by a 'head seek' time to the actual beginning of the file cylinder,

followed by a 'sector seek' time to get over the correct sector,

followed by the actual data transfer time.

subsequent reads will not include the accessing of the directory info.

Any access can (but not always) include some 'head seek' time (which varies in length and depends on where the heads are currently located and where the desire data is currently located.

With buffering, the subsequent access times are greatly reduced (on most reads) because the actual transfer will include multiple sectors so only occasionally needs to actually access the disk.

When not buffered, a lot depends on if the disk, itself, performs any buffering (these days, most do perform local buffering)   Accessing data that is already in the disk buffer eliminates all seek times (head and sector) making the transfer much faster.

Comment: All right, the results make a lot more sense now. I do have one question though. For the buffered case, the access times stabilise after the first 3 block accesses. Shouldn't they stabilise after the very first access itself? Or is it that some additional metadata access is happening (or something totally different)?

Comment: I suspect that delayed stabilization of the access times may be a combination of things.  Things like: other applications and/or the OS running that access the disk,  When a 'read ahead' situation is triggered, how good/smart is  the disk device driver and other factors over which we have no real control such as how fast the program is ready for another record from the disk, compared to how fast the disk can serve up that next record.  (the disk access is orders of magnitude slower than the (typical) time between when a program processes one disk record and when it requests the next